# Как в эти 2 кода внедрить прелоудер (спинер)

Tags: ajax

Как в эти 2 кода внедрить прелоудер (спинер)? В один код просто добавить а в другой вместо надписи "загружаю". Примеров нигде не нашел

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
     var bottomOffset = 3000; // отступ от нижней границы сайта, до которого должен доскроллить пользователь, чтобы подгрузились новые посты
     var data = {
         'action': 'loadmore',
         'query': posts_vars,
         'page': current_page
     };
     if ($(document).scrollTop() > ($(document).height() - bottomOffset) && !$('body').hasClass('loading')) {
         $.ajax({
             url: ajaxurl,
             data: data,
             type: 'POST',
             beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                 $('body').addClass('loading');
             },
             success: function (data) {
                 if (data) {
                     $('#true_loadmore').before(data);
                     $('body').removeClass('loading');
                     current_page++;

                     if (current_page == max_pages) $('#btn_loadmore').remove(); // если последняя страница, удаляем кнопку
                 } else {
                     $('#btn_loadmore').remove(); // если мы дошли до последней страницы постов, скроем кнопку
                 }
             }
         });
     }
 });


jQuery(function($){
    $('#true_loadmore').click(function(){
        $(this).text('Загружаю...'); // изменяем текст кнопки, вы также можете добавить прелоадер
        var data = {
            'action': 'loadmore',
            'query': true_posts,
            'page' : current_page
        };
        $.ajax({
            url:ajaxurl, // обработчик
            data:data, // данные
            type:'POST', // тип запроса
            success:function(data){
                if( data ) { 
                    $('#true_loadmore').text('Загрузить ещё').before(data); // вставляем новые посты
                    current_page++; // увеличиваем номер страницы на единицу
                    if (currentPage == maxPages) $("#true_loadmore").remove(); // если последняя страница, удаляем кнопку
                } else {
                    $('#true_loadmore').remove(); // если мы дошли до последней страницы постов, скроем кнопку
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: А сейчас что не так? в первом коде всё есть...на втором надо просто текст обратно поменять в методе success

Comment: Нужно при подгрузке постов показать гиф анимацию на весь экран. Но с другими ajax запросами на этой же странице должны быть другие спинеры в других местах

Comment: А сейчас что не так? в первом коде всё есть...на втором надо просто текст обратно поменять в методе success